# How to fix System Menu in new install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: 22.04, menu, system-settings, menu-bar

I want the system menu that's shown in the Ubuntu docs, here:

[image]

This is what I have, which is limited, and doesn't match the instructions I see Googling (such as hidden wifi):

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @user535733  Ok.  Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website image is from a newer release of Ubuntu, which runs a newer release of Gnome.

Ubuntu has had three releases after 22.04, and is working on a fourth.

To get the newer-looking menu, you must run a newer release of Ubuntu.

Advanced users can try to backport newer Gnome to older releases, but it's a big, complex, lengthy task. A whole team of full-time professional engineers familiar with Gnome spends a full week (or more) integrating Gnome into Ubuntu every release cycle. Not for beginners.

Comment: Thanks. I want to stick with LTS. --- Any idea how to Google for 22.04 instructions? I was trying to connect to a hidden wifi network, and every Google match showed an "all networks," which I don't have. (It says "visible networks.) That's what motivated this post. I finally gave up on Google and clicked on everything I saw on every screen, systematically. I have to go to settings -> wifi -> three dots -> Connect to hidden network. I already knew the process would be easier if I had connected while it wasn't hidden - so it was listed under hidden networks.